# Custom Control binding property

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I have created a custom control but I can't bind a property to the content like this :

```
<Style TargetType="control:Pie">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:Pie">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And in my control

```
public string Test
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Test",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Pie),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

When I create the control a set a string in the Test property but nothing appears in the view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` is used to bind to the templated control and therefore only works in `ControlTemplate`. Just 2 Lines above you already used TemplateBinding for Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness.

`Binding` on the otherhand binds to the `DataContext`, which is an object used to take "business" related data from the user. It should be independant of how your controls works and

As a rule of thumb: If you use a normal binding in a `ControlTemplate`, which doesn't have a `RelativeSource`, `ElementName` or `Source` set, it usually should not appear in a ControlTemplate or Style.